# Adding Your own license agreement in WIX Bootstrapper Project

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.7

How can i add my own license file in WIX Bootstrapper project.
I have a WIX Bootstrapper project that installed a chain of MSIs but i want to display my own license file when setup starts.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Bundle Name="Biodentify 2014 Setup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Microsoft" UpgradeCode="4056d930-16b2-44eb-a861-16db566ae44c">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
  <!--<PackageGroupRef Id="BONJOUR"/>-->

  <MsiPackage  SourceFile=".\A.msi" Compressed="yes" />
  <MsiPackage  SourceFile=".\B.msi" Compressed="yes" />
  <MsiPackage  SourceFile=".\C.msi" Compressed="yes" />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile ="$(var.Setup.TargetPath)" Compressed ="yes" DisplayInternalUI="yes" />

    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense` common bootstrapper application, all you have to do is set `BootstrapperApplicationRef/bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication/@LicenseFile` to the name of an RTF file in the bundle.

The example from [the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_license.html) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseFile="path\to\license.rtf"
        LogoFile="path\to\customlogo.png" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Chain>
      ...
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Note you will need to add a reference to `WixBalExtension` in your project as well as the namespace declaration.